# access methods and variables in first navigation controller from pushed view

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I normally use UIViews to make my apps - but this one I am using a navigationcontroller. I am pushing a view to the top where I want to add items to an array. However, I cannot access the main navigation controller methods etc. Here's the set up

1) AppDelegate adds navigation controller

```
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

2) In RootViewController I push a new UIView

```
AddNewViewController *addNewViewController = [[AddNewViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController: addNewViewController animated:YES];
```

3) From the AddNewViewController I then want to access the main RootViewController - but cannot seem to access anything. All the methods etc are declared as I've done it before (using UIViews). This code cannot find anything in the RootViewController.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.navigationController myFunction];
```

I have myFunction in the RootViewController.h file. I have used this method before, but never with a navigation controller. I guess it's something to do with hte stack - but I cannot find out what I've done wrong!

Help is much appreciated!!

*** UPDATE ***

I have now used

```
AddNewViewController *addNewViewController = [[AddNewViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:addNewViewController animated:YES];
```

to push the view controller. In my code, I am trying to access the tableview to reload it with the following code

```
[self.navigationController.mainTableView reloadData];
```

but the mainTableView is not accessible. I have declared and sync'd it but still cannot see it. I also tried to loop through and use the element[0] of the stack (as below) but didn't get anywhere with that either!

```
NSArray *controllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationController.viewControllers, nil];

UIViewController *tmpController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
tmpController = [controllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: In which method you want to access self.navigationController? If you try to access it before the view is pushed on the stack self.navigationController is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,

```
[self presentModalViewController: addNewViewController animated:YES];
```

does something different than

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:addNewViewController animated:YES];
```

The names of those methods should speak for themselves.

---

And appDelegate.navigationController is not **your** rootViewController. It is the UINavigationController. You can get an NSArray of viewControllers attached to the navigationcontroller with self.navigationController.viewControllers. Item at index 0 should be your rootViewController.

If you push the viewController on the navigationControllers stack there is no need to use the appdelegate. You can access the navigationController with self.navigationController.

Comment: ah that makes sense - thanks for the pushviewcontroller code too. I have changed it to that and it feels much better. I have updated my post above with the new code.